# How does CAD save 3d shapes? and can I read from it?

Tags: autocad, cad

For example, how does CAD save such a 3d shape?

[image]
I mean, does it save it like something:

```
points = [[0,0,0],[0,1,0],[1,1,0],[1,0,0]]
lines = [[points[1], points[2]],[points[2],points[3]]]
```

Because I want to draw some 3d shapes(in python and render it in webpages), and I want to know how they are stored in files.

Comment: Do you need to write/read only points/lines or even faces?

Comment: @Alberto, well.. whatever that it takes to make a 3d shape. In my case, I only interested in these `prism-like` 3d shapes.

Comment: Yours is a wireframe geometry, it cannot be shaded. In order to help you, it's important to understand if you need to fill each face or you are satisfied with lines only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from web-sites such as [this one](http://fileinfo.com/filetypes/cad), there's no "one format to rule them all."  Every CAD program *(like every other computer program ...)* wound up defining "its own, app-specific format." AutoCAD is just one of many. But there are also various "standard" *(sic ...)* formats ... almost-inevitably "XML-based" ... which were specifically designed to allow model-information to be shared among programs.  Typically, you "export" the model to one of these formats.

"And then, you Google to find where *somebody else(!)* has already perfected a Python module that knows how to read that file-format."  You can be *quite* sure that you will **not** have to write-and-debug that code yourself.  (After all, "you are not the *first* soul to have needed to do this sort of thing ...")

Normally, you *don't* try to deal with "the application's *native* format," because, even if the vendor in question actually saw fit to publish it, it contains "everything, including the kitchen sink."  Stuff that you don't need.  An "export file" is usually preferable for (and, was designed for ...) this very reason.

Comment: Well, actually I'm developing a small 3d shape match program, but not sure how 3d shapes are stored. And that's the reason I want to know how they are stored in `dwg`.

Answer (score 0):

you may consider use Autodesk 3d webgl viewer technology, see a running sample for end-users at https://360.autodesk.com/viewer and check the full API (REST & JavaScript) at https://developer.autodesk.com/